# Is it safe/right to store objects in application memory?

Tags: android, flutter

In my flutter application, I want to access some data on many pages. So I created static final variables and assigned the data on app startup.

My doubt is, if the application is so long in the background, will the os remove the object and that cause the app to crash or something when the app resumes?

Comment: I'm not a Flutter user, so can't give a detailed answer. If you hold all your data in memory, it becomes more likely that the application will kill your whole app to free memory. It won't selectively free up objects that there are references to and create a crash, though. Your app is always at risk of being killed to free memory, whether or not its using a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**, you can store that variable without any problem, at least for **android** (not sure about others). But if you are using that in **foreground service**, you should make a member variable of that *data/object in your class.*

Bcz, in java, GC does not finalize the object until there is at least one reference that is been used.